# adding directive to a angular 2 component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I recently created a simple project using angular 2. When I try to add a directive component to the app.component, there's a red underline for 'directives' property. 
Anybody tell me what's wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Directives, components, and pipes need to be added to

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...]
```

since RC.6

`directives`, and `pipes` was removed from `@Component()` back then.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-27

Comment: @echonax - Is this the official one?

Comment: @Günter - Thank you very much. I didn't know that. Sorry I can't vote up any of your answers since I don't have 15 reputations.

Comment: @Rozane yes it is the official changelog. If Günter's answer helped you, you should mark his answer as accepted :-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826

Comment: @Rozane yes, it's the official. No worries.

Comment: @echonax - Done. I didn't know that feature ;) Thanks both